# Upload image to azure blob storage using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an image directory named `images` which contains image files as:

```
images
    --0001.png
    --0002.jpg
    --0003.png
```

Now I want to upload this directory to my azure blob storage with the same file structure. I looked at the sample code given [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-python-quickstart/blob/master/example.py) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob) but:

1. Even after installing `azure-blob-storage`, there is no such thing as `BlobService` in that package.
2. Is there any place where it is clearly documented how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my sample code works fine for me.

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

root_path = '<your root path>'
dir_name = 'images'
path = f"{root_path}/{dir_name}"
file_names = os.listdir(path)

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
container_name = '<your container name, such as `test` for me>'

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)

for file_name in file_names:
    blob_name = f"{dir_name}/{file_name}"
    file_path = f"{path}/{file_name}"
    block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, blob_name, file_path)
```

The result as the figure below be screenshot from [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/).

[image]

For more details about API references of Azure Storage SDK for Python, please refer to https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/index.html.

---

Update: My used Python version is Python 3.7.4 on Windows, and the required package is `azure-storage==0.36.0`, you can find it from https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage/.

1. `$ virtualenv test`
2. `$ cd test`
3. `$ Scripts\active`
4. `$ pip install azure-storage`

Then, you can run my sample code via `python upload_images.py` in the current Python virtual environment.

Comment: The thing is that even after install `azure-blob-storage`, there is no `BlockBlobService` in this package.

Comment: @mlRocks Please init the Python virtual env and install the `azure-storage` package. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 6):

It's in the documentation that you linked.

It's not `BlobService`, it is `BlobClient` class.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(
        conn_str='my_conn_str',
        container_name='my_container_name',
        blob_name='my_blob_name')

with open("./SampleSource.txt", "rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data)
```

See the [BlobClient.from_connection_string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-from-connection-string) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there are two versions of azure.storage.blob . If you create a Azure VM and process data there, you can end up with either one of them.

The older version requires (as pointed out by Adam Marczak):

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string("my_connection_string", container="mycontainer", blob="my_blob")

with open("./SampleSource.txt", "rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data)
```

while the newer:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)

blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
    container_name, blob_name ,  full_file_path )
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, neither **create_blob_from_bytes** nor BlockBlobService exists in the latest python SDK[1] which you get by default unless you are managing the versions of various packages.

I am assuming you might want to execute this as a standalone script. So you can authenticate using **AzureCliCredential**[2] and retrieve the necessary resource endpoints via the methods provided in the SDK.

> Below code won't work in the Azure Functions.

```
    from azure.storage.blob import (
       BlobServiceClient,
       ContentSettings
    )

    storage_connection_string='DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>;AccountKey=<ACCOUNT_KEY>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
    container_name =
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.(
        conn_str=storage_connection_string
        )
    logging.debug(f'getting client for container : {container_name}')
    container_client = 
    blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)
    if blob_client.exists():
        blob_client.delete_blob()
    blob_client =blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, 
    blob=blob_name)
    try:
        with open(filename, "rb") as data:
             blob.upload(data)
        content_settings =ContentSettings(content_type='image/png')
        logging.debug(f'setting the content type : {content_settings}')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(str(e))
```

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.azureclicredential?view=azure-python

Answer (score 0):

```
def upload_file(remote_path,local_path):
    try:
        blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name=SETTINGS.AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=SETTINGS.AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY)
        blobService.create_blob_from_path('data',remote_path,local_path)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f'Unable to save azure blob data. {str(e)}')
        raise Exception(f'Unable to save azure blob data. {str(e)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient,ContentSettings

blob = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, container_name=container_name, blob_name="my_blob9")
image_content_setting = ContentSettings(content_type='image/jpeg')

with open("/content/sample_data/kanha.png","rb") as data:
    blob.upload_blob(data,overwrite=True,content_settings=image_content_setting)
```

Comment: if you want to upload as png/jpeg/original file then you can upload using this code else for binary you can check ```https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#create-a-container```