# Uploading csv files to azure container using SAS URI in python?

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to upload files to azure using the SAS URI only. I found ways using C# but I didn't find a solution using python. The only solution I found using python is to input the account name and account key as parameters in blockblobservice. Here is an example [Upload image to azure blob storage using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816849/upload-image-to-azure-blob-storage-using-python) but I am trying to avoid using this solution. Is there a specific way to upload csv files to azure using only the SAS URI ? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: what about this? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_authentication.py#L80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the latest python blob sdk [azure-storage-blob 12.4.0](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-blob/), then you can use the code like below(please feel free to modify the code as per your need):

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient

upload_file_path="d:\\a11.csv"
sas_url="https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/test5/a11.csv?sastoken"

client = BlobClient.from_blob_url(sas_url)

with open(upload_file_path,'rb') as data:
    client.upload_blob(data)

print("**file uploaded**")
```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#upload-blobs-to-a-container

Example is shown by using the Python SDK for Azure Storage