# Upload files to a Container in Azure Blob Storage using Python

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload a couple of files to a container. I have tried the approaches mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816849/upload-image-to-azure-blob-storage-using-python) but it did not work.

Here's what I have:

SAS URL: `https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net?sp=acw&st=2022-05-31T17:54:22Z&se=2022-06-05T10:59:59Z&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=H0g%2BY%2FOnNIaYNVTsX%2FP42buWaowxIlxQDJ0xqH0gvqQ%3D`

Container Name: `XYZ`

I want to upload the files to the container root, without any subfolders.

Edit:
My code so far:

```
sas = 'https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net?sp=acw&st=2022-05-31T17:54:22Z&se=2022-06-05T10:59:59Z&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=H0g%2BY%2FOnNIaYNVTsX%2FP42buWaowxIlxQDJ0xqH0gvqQ%3D'

container = 'container_name'
sasUrlParts = urlparse(sas)
accountEndpoint = sasUrlParts.scheme + '://' + sasUrlParts.netloc
sasToken = sasUrlParts.query

blobSasUrl = accountEndpoint + '/' + container + '?' + sasToken

blobClient = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blobSasUrl)

with open('/file_to_be_uploaded.csv', 'rb') as f:
    blobClient.upload_blob(f)
```

which produces the following error in the line `blobClient = BlobClient.from_blob_url(blobSasUrl)`:

```
ValueError: Invalid URL. Provide a blob_url with a valid blob and container name
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written so far and the issues you’re running into with that.

Comment: @GauravMantri Please check the edit.

Comment: Did you check the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=environment-variable-windows#upload-blobs-to-a-container)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the reason you're getting the error is because your `blobSasUrl` does not include the name of the blob.

Please try by changing the following line of code:

```
blobSasUrl = accountEndpoint + '/' + container + '?' + sasToken
```

to

```
blobName = 'file_to_be_uploaded.csv'
blobSasUrl = accountEndpoint + '/' + container + '/' + blobName + '?' + sasToken
```

And you should not get the error you are getting.

Comment: It ran successfully. Thanks! Is there a way to check if it had been uploaded correctly? I don't have read access to this container.

Comment: If you do not get an error, that would mean the blob uploaded successfully.